# Passwords on imported customers in prestashop - from miva merchant

Tags: encryption, passwords, prestashop

I am working to migrate an existing online store from Miva Merchant to Prestashop.  One issue I'm having is customers' passwords.  When I export customers from Miva Merchant, an example password field looks like this:

```
PBKDF1:sha1:1000:W86eGcNGtpk=:ZZNLmbF5f8dcR2j70FkCYpFX90U=
```

Obviously, I'll need to modify prestashop's password verification code, but what am I supposed to modify it to?  Currently, the passwords are being checked with (roughly):

```
md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd)
```

If the encrypted value matches the one stored in the database, the authentication succeeds.  what encryption do I need to deal with?

It seems that I'm dealing with pbkdf1 byte derivation using sha1 algorithm, likely with 1000 iterations.  However what are the other two fields? One of them probably represents salt, the other - the actual password hash, but which is which?  The pbkdf1 algorithm produces bytes, so they need to somehow be converted to a printable string - but how?  And what is the length being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a lot more digging and creative googling - and I found my answer: [this great Miva_Password](https://github.com/Brandon0/Miva_Password/blob/master/src/Miva_Password.php) PHP class by Brandon0 on GitHub.  I created a simple test - and managed to match the password hash.  Unfortunately, to do this properly, I'd have to make quite a few changes to `classes/Customer.php` class in Prestashop to replace the current md5 hashing with the Miva algorithm.

I'll try to convince the client to just import the customers without passwords - so that they would need to reset their passwords on the next visit.  Hopefully, they'll agree.  If not, then I'll have to make all the changes.